# Monic polynomials clarification

Tags: polynomials

So I know a monic polynomial is one where the coefficient of the leading term is 1, but does that mean the constant 1 is a monic polynomial too?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is a monic polynomial (the only one) of degree $0$. There might be times when books assume lazily that a monic polynomial is non-constant - in which case, they really mean "non-constant monic polynomial."

Comment: Oh, cool. Thanks.